# How can I use a generic constructor in interface implementation?

Tags: java, data-structures

The question might be not clear I will show you what I want in below

I have a generic list interface like this :

```
public interface List<Type> {
    void add(Type t);
    Type get(int index);
    void clear();
    Type remove(int index);
}
```

And implementation with an example because it's too long:

```
@Override   
public abstract class DoublyLinkedList<Type> implements List<Type> {
    public void add(Type t) {
        // create new node
        Node<Type> newNode=new Node<>(t, null,null);
        newNode.data = t;
        newNode.previous = tail;
        newNode.next = null;

        // if list is empty
        if (tail == null)
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.next = newNode;
        }
        tail = newNode;
    }
}
```

and have a constructor:

```
public abstract class Node<Type> {

    protected Type data;
    protected Node<Type> next;
    protected Node<Type> previous;

    public Node(Type data, Node<Type> next,Node<Type> previous) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous = previous;

    }

    public Type getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node<Type> getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public Node<Type> getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }
}
```

it already gives errors I know but I saw something like that before to use in interface implementation a constructor:

```
public interface SortedList<Type extends Comparable<? super Type>>
```

So, can I use that, and how?

Comment: Your Node class is abstract, so you can't instantiate it. If you change it to concrete class, the error goes away.

Comment: @Eran then it gives The method add(List<Type>, Type) of type DoublyLinkedList<Type> must override or implement a supertype method (error) in methods.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler thinks DoublyLinkedList is implementing java.util.List instead of your custom List interface. Try renaming your List interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I could find is that you are tying to create an instance of Node but Node is abstract. Just removing abstract from Node helps to compile the code.

```
public class Node<Type> {

    protected Type data;
    protected Node<Type> next;
    protected Node<Type> previous;

    public Node(Type data, Node<Type> next,Node<Type> previous) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous = previous;

    }

    public Type getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node<Type> getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public Node<Type> getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }
}
```